# using React Router with browserHisory

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, browser-history, react-router-redux

I'm developing an app which consists in React + Redux.
We just turned it into a SPA with React Router.

While searching the web, I see everybody uses brwoserHistory on their router.

```
<Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
    ....
</Router>
```

I understand the concept of history, and see the advantages of controlling the history stack.

Currently, I'm not using it and it works fine,  I'm new to React Router and I want to know if i need it.

Answer (score 0):

A history **object** to use for **navigation**.

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

const customHistory = createBrowserHistory()
<Router history={customHistory}/>
```

more info [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Router.md)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get what it is used for, what i don't understand is, if it is usefull in future. Currently we don't use it and we are just fine